# Magento PHP Extension intl - XAMPP

Tags: php, magento, xampp

I tried to install Magento on localhost (XAMPP) for the first time today. As Magento installer does the Readiness Check an error occurs, as it is missing PHP Extension intl. I have done research, but all I can find is to remove `;` from **";extension=php_intl.dll"** in `php.ini` in etc folder. This does not work (tried to restart XAMPP and the computer several times)

This is driving me crazy, please help.

I am on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check with phpinfo() method to check intl loaded or not. some time may this loaded bud you are in the mistakes.
after that, check php_intl.dll existin this folder : **"\xampp\php\ext"**
if all of these are ok, you may check log files.

**UPDATE**:

Base on your update about OS,if you have homebrew available and have PHP7:

```
$ brew install php70-intl // For PHP7.0
$ brew install php71-intl // For PHP7.1
```

For PHP5.5:

```
$ brew install php55-intl
```

Re-open your terminal window to ensure it works right in your session. To see if it loaded via your CLI interpreter:

```
$ php -m | grep intl
```

**Or**:

```
$ php -i "(command-line 'phpinfo()')" | grep intl
```

**Source**: https://daveismyname.blog/blog/install-php-intl-on-mac-using-homebrew

Comment: Can't find the php_intl.dll. Can I download it from somewhere?

Comment: How do I find if the php_intl.dll has been loaded with the phpinfo()? I have tried to search for "intl" with CTRL + F. which gives zero results.

Comment: *.dll Uses for windows base application. I update my answer base on your update ;)  @Melvin

Comment: I am so sorry, but it still does not work. I have searched a lot and try many different methods, and as I try ”php -m | grep intl” it returns intl, but magento still can not find the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your correct php.ini file and also create a php file with a function phpinfo() and run this file and check the extension that are not installed.

To enable/installed these extension go to php.ini file and uncomment those extension.

save this file and restart the `apache/xampp`

I hope it will work for you.